# Block level text tags; intelligent CSS margins

Tags: html, css, tags, stylesheet, margin

I use a CSS reset which zeros out the margin and padding of *most*-everything (*it's an altered version of the [Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) reset*), including of course block level text tags.

I'm trying to reinstate the text margins, but only on block level text tags that are followed by block level text tags.

Is there any way more manageable than the following to achieve this?

```
h1 + h1, h1 + h2, h1 + h3, h1 + h4,
h1 + ol, h1 + ul, h1 + p, h2 + h1,
h2 + h2, h2 + h3, h2 + h4, h2 + ol,
h2 + ul, h2 + p, h3 + h1, h3 + h2,
h3 + h3, h3 + h4, h3 + ol, h3 + ul,
h3 + p, h4 + h1, h4 + h2, h4 + h3,
h4 + h4, h4 + ol, h4 + ul, h4 + p,
ol + h1, ol + h2, ol + h3, ol + h4,
ol + ol, ol + ul, ol + p, ul + h1,
ul + h2, ul + h3, ul + h4, ul + ol,
ul + ul, ul + p, p + h1, p + h2,
p + h3, p + h4, p + ol, p + ul,
p + p{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

I know this is incomplete (*`blockquote`, etc.*) but it paints the picture.

---

More complete version: This adds space between non-identical block level text elements; for example, it will add between `h1 + p`, but not `h2 + h2` (*note, I'm not using this specifically, but this is something I may resort to unless a better alternative surfaces*)
<sub>(*also note, I just realized this excludes some combinations like `p + p`. Just pretend they're in there*)</sub>

```
h1 + h2, h1 + h3, h1 + h4, h1 + ol, h1 + ul, h1 + p,
h1 + dl, h1 + pre, h1 + blockquote, h1 + address, h2 + h1, h2 + h3,
h2 + h4, h2 + ol, h2 + ul, h2 + p, h2 + dl, h2 + pre,
h2 + blockquote, h2 + address, h3 + h1, h3 + h2, h3 + h4, h3 + ol,
h3 + ul, h3 + p, h3 + dl, h3 + pre, h3 + blockquote, h3 + address,
h4 + h1, h4 + h2, h4 + h3, h4 + ol, h4 + ul, h4 + p,
h4 + dl, h4 + pre, h4 + blockquote, h4 + address, ol + h1, ol + h2,
ol + h3, ol + h4, ol + ul, ol + p, ol + dl, ol + pre,
ol + blockquote, ol + address, ul + h1, ul + h2, ul + h3, ul + h4,
ul + ol, ul + p, ul + dl, ul + pre, ul + blockquote, ul + address,
p + h1, p + h2, p + h3, p + h4, p + ol, p + ul,
p + dl, p + pre, p + blockquote, p + address, dl + h1, dl + h2,
dl + h3, dl + h4, dl + ol, dl + ul, dl + p, dl + pre,
dl + blockquote, dl + address, pre + h1, pre + h2, pre + h3, pre + h4,
pre + ol, pre + ul, pre + p, pre + dl, pre + blockquote, pre + address,
blockquote + h1, blockquote + h2, blockquote + h3, blockquote + h4, blockquote + ol, blockquote + ul,
blockquote + p, blockquote + dl, blockquote + pre, blockquote + address, address + h1, address + h2,
address + h3, address + h4, address + ol, address + ul, address + p, address + dl,
address + pre, address + blockquote{
    margin-top: 0.625em;
}
```

Comment: This is why you don't use a `* { margin: 0; }` CSS reset. And what's a "block-level text tag"? From the selectors you're using I can't make out what you define that to be.

Comment: @BoltClock - If you want to go through and get rid of every specific style for each specific site/app you create - then go ahead. Quite a few people like being able to just plug something in and start working, without worrying about browser inconsistencies (which is the main thing a reset addresses)

Comment: @djlumley: Actually, I never intend to "get rid of every specific style". I use my own reset but a reset doesn't have to zero out literally ***EVERYTHING*** for ***EVERY ELEMENT***.

Comment: @BoltClock - That's fine. I'm not debating whether a complete reset is good or bad, just that it has its merits.

Comment: @Boltclock & djlumley - I'm using a slightly modified version of the Meyer reset, not the universal `margin: 0;`. As for "block level text", I'm referring to elements that are by default rendered as block, such as `h1`, `p`, etc. Essentially any text element which semantically is a "block" of text, typically delimited vertically by some sort of visual cue, in this case space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be overcoding here, that is, trying to anticipate every situation when many situations will never or seldom occur.

For instance, I think it highly unlikely that you will need to style

`h1 + h1`

as that *should not* appear in your code.

Same goes for many of the header to header combos.

Moreover, if you are doing this

`h1 + p` and `p + h1` and `h1 + h1` and `p + p` and all the other variations,

than you might as well do

`h1, p { // }`

My advice would be the same as [@Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908378/pawel-adamski), just do

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol //and others// {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

If you must do it your suggested way, I would simplify as follows

```
h1 + ol, h1 + ul, h1 + p,
h2 + ol, h2 + ul, h2 + p,
h3 + ol, h3 + ul, h3 + p,
h4 + ol, h4 + ul, h4 + p{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

...and then style other configurations only as need be.

Comment: Thanks @Jason - My edit supports the first scenario you mentioned; `h1 + h1` *should not* appear, er go they were excluded (*stupidly, so was `p + p`, but I just spewed that from a one liner script*) The only caveat that Pawel (*and your*) suggestion doesn't cover is when the element is the first-child... which could be solved by `:first-child`. You're certainly correct that I am over-coding, but a catch-all would be nice.

Comment: Agreed @Bracketworks, a catch-all would be great!  But I don't see it, unfortunately. ;-(

Comment: Yea @Jason the *other* alternative I've considered is instead doing `margin-bottom: 0.5em;` on all text elements, and perhaps a `*:last-child{ margin-bottom: 0.5em; }` I'll have to play around with it when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

While not the *ideal* solution, the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) contains a CSS reset called [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) that attempts to keep basic styling.

It's not exactly what you're after, but might give you some ideas.

Additionally, depending on the way you're doing things, something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) might make managing your CSS while you develop this a little easier.

Comment: I've been hearing about normalize.css and it's tickled my interest. I'll have to try it for my next project.

Comment: Thanks @djlumley - I perused normalize.css, and while it is certainly insightful (*and a good candidate for subsequent projects*) it doesn't appear to provide any solution here. I've also considered LESS for it's wealth of benefits, but again, likely in another project. I'm more curious about a quick-fix so to speak, something that will (*for the most part*) just intelligently delimit text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ?

Is this what you wanted?

EDIT: (how about)

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,
 form, label, ul, ol, dl, fieldset, address {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: He's asking how to add margins between text based block level elements after applying this sort of reset as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel - This unfortunately won't solve the problem, I'm trying to add space to each block text element that **is not** the first block text element of it's adjacent siblings.